# Querying larg table without extending tablespace in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, oracle12c, tablespace

I have a DB table (used for a queue) that is holding alot rows.
Now I'm looking for the oldest entries to see when thes have been enqueued by running the query:

```
SELECT * FROM DB_SCHEMA.WORKER ORDER BY ENQ_TIME ASC;
```

But what I get after some time is only:

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
*Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
           a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
*Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
           files to the tablespace indicated.
```

Is there a way - without extending the table space - to get the entries of the oldest enqueued row?
Is there a way to optimize the query?

The database is a Oracle 12c

The table looks like:

```
NAME    TYPE
-------------------------
Q_NAME  VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
MSGID   RAW
CORRID  VARCHAR2(128 CHAR)
PRIORITY    NUMBER
STATE   NUMBER
DELAY   TIMESTAMP(6)
EXPIRATION  NUMBER
TIME_MANAGER_INFO   TIMESTAMP(6)
LOCAL_ORDER_NO  NUMBER
CHAIN_NO    NUMBER
CSCN    NUMBER
DSCN    NUMBER
ENQ_TIME    TIMESTAMP(6)
ENQ_UID VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
ENQ_TID VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
DEQ_TIME    TIMESTAMP(6)
DEQ_UID VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
DEQ_TID VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
RETRY_COUNT NUMBER
EXCEPTION_QSCHEMA   VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
EXCEPTION_QUEUE VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
STEP_NO NUMBER
RECIPIENT_KEY   NUMBER
DEQUEUE_MSGID   RAW
SENDER_NAME VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
SENDER_ADDRESS  VARCHAR2(1024 CHAR)
SENDER_PROTOCOL NUMBER
USER_DATA   AQ$_JMS_MESSAGE
```

Comment: yeah it is trying to sort all the rows.  What is "a lot of row"?  Is there an index on ENQ_TIME ? can you add a constraint of some sorts on the query, ie "where ENQ_TIME  < xxxx"?

Comment: Are you able to find `min(ENQ_TIME)`

Comment: if you just one 1 row, try something like this : select * from (SELECT * FROM DB_SCHEMA.WORKER ORDER BY ENQ_TIME ASC) where rownum=1

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to avoid running out of temporary tablespace (other than simply increasing the available space):

1. **Select fewer columns.** An `ORDER BY` clause requires sorting, and Oracle's sorting use about as much memory as the size of the data. When the intermediate results can't fit in memory, they are written to the temporary tablespace. That intermediate result set size can be shrunk by replacing `*` with only the necessary columns.
2. **Select fewer rows.** Similar to the above suggestion, reduce the amount of data by filtering some of the rows out.
3. **Use index for sorting.** Indexes are pre-sorted data structures. Since the work was already done when the data was inserted, Oracle doesn't need to re-sort when reading the data back. Create an index on `ENQ_TIME` and make sure that the column is `NOT NULL`. Oracle indexes do not normally include null values, so if you can't make the column `NOT NULL` you can create the index like `(ENQ_TIME, 1)`.

   However, indexes don't always work well for retrieving large amounts of data, so Oracle may still use a full table scan followed by a sort. Oracle doesn't know that you're only interested in the first N rows, but you can tell it by adding a hint like `/*+ first_rows(100) */`. Hints are usually a bad idea, but this is a good hint because you're giving the optimizer useful information. With the index, constraint, and hint, you should see the operation `INDEX FULL SCAN` in the explain plan, which should not use any temporary tablespace.

You can check the temporary segment usage with `GV$TEMPSEG_USAGE.BLOCKS`.